# question about a $7\times 5$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix $A$ of order $7\times5$ and of rank $4$. Let $P$ and $Q$ be the projection matrices that project vectors in $\mathbb R^7$ onto $R(A)$ and $N(A^T)$, respectively.

I have to show that:

a) $PQ=0$

b) $P+Q=I$.

For the question a) I have that $R(A)$ represents the range of matrix $A$ and $N(A^T)$ is the Null space of $A$ transpose. These are orthogonal complements so when you multiply vectors from these bases together you get $0$. Is that enough?

And I don't really know about the b).

Answer (score 0):

For 1) you're right. For 2), notice that the rank of $P$ is $4$ and the rank of $Q$ is $7-4=3$ and as you noticed, they project onto orthogonal spaces. This means that $P+Q$ is a projector on space of full dimension $7$, which is clearly the identity operator.